# how to get data after successful validation in php

Tags: php, validation

Hi i'm at processing my form and validation process , so far so good
i got a php script that validate my fields as i want but i'm a novice in php and dont know where should i code this part

```
    if( isset($_POST['name']) )
    {
        $to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; 
        $subject = 'NEWLOGO CLIENT FORM'; 
        $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email'];
$message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
               'Surname: ' . $_POST['surname'] . "\n" .
               'E-mail: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n" .
               'Phone: ' . $_POST['phone']. "\n" .
```

inside this

```
<?php

require_once('validator.php');

if(isset($_POST['form_btn'])) {

    $validator = new simple_fv;

    $fields = array();

    $fields[] = array('index'=>'name', 'label'=>'Name', 'required'=>true, 'max_len'=>25);
    $fields[] = array('index'=>'surname', 'label'=>'surname', 'required'=>true, 'max_len'=>30);
    $fields[] = array('index'=>'slider1-value', 'label'=>'Simple vs Complex');
    $fields[] = array('index'=>'slider2-value', 'label'=>'Young vs Mature');
    $fields[] = array('index'=>'slider3-value', 'label'=>'Luxury vs Economical');
    $fields[] = array('index'=>'slider4-value', 'label'=>'Modern vs Classic');
     $fields[] = array('index'=>'slider5-value', 'label'=>'Luxury vs Economical');


    // validate the fields
    $validator->formHandle($fields);

    // get errors
    $error = $validator->getErrors();

    // if errors is not FALSE - print the succesfull message
    if($error) {echo $error;}
    else {echo 'SUCCESFULL MESSAGE'; }  
}

?>
```

This is just a part of my form .
each time tried it sends me the data without validating it in php .
and possibly how to bring the user back after the   `else {echo 'SUCCESFULL MESSAGE'; }` 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the simple_fv class?

Comment: how do you mean , should i code it there ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `form_val` to get the values

```
<?php

require_once('validator.php');

if(isset($_POST['form_btn'])) {

    $validator = new simple_fv;

    $fields = array();

    $fields[] = array('index'=>'name', 'label'=>'Name', 'required'=>true, 'max_len'=>25);
    $fields[] = array('index'=>'surname', 'label'=>'surname', 'required'=>true, 'max_len'=>30);
    $fields[] = array('index'=>'slider1-value', 'label'=>'Simple vs Complex');
    $fields[] = array('index'=>'slider2-value', 'label'=>'Young vs Mature');
    $fields[] = array('index'=>'slider3-value', 'label'=>'Luxury vs Economical');
    $fields[] = array('index'=>'slider4-value', 'label'=>'Modern vs Classic');
    $fields[] = array('index'=>'slider5-value', 'label'=>'Luxury vs Economical');


    // validate the fields
    $validator->formHandle($fields);

    // get errors
    $error = $validator->getErrors();

    // if errors is not FALSE - print the succesfull message
    if($error) {
        echo $error;
    }else {
        echo 'SUCCESFULL VALIDATION!'; 
        //send mail
        $fdata = $validator->form_val;
        $to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; 
        $subject = 'NEWLOGO CLIENT FORM'; 
        $headers = 'From: ' . $fdata['email'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $fdata['email'];
        $message = 'Name: ' . $fdata['name'] . "\n" .
                   'Surname: ' . $fdata['surname'] . "\n" .
                   'E-mail: ' . $fdata['email'] . "\n" .
                   'Phone: ' . $fdata['phone']. "\n" .
        //.............
        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers){
            echo 'SUCCESFULL VALIDATION';
        }else{
            echo 'FAILED TO SEND';
        }

    }  
}

?>
```

Comment: @NewLogo after `$validator->formHandle($fields);` do `var_dump($validator->form_val)`

Comment: again the same .. @meda

Comment: could you please write the code before again i may have made a mistake here

Comment: @NewLogo ok I rolled back, im not sure why getting a property would give you internal server error

Comment: i don't know also again i'm getting the same error :S i could send you a ftp user name if you dont mind and you could give it an eye yourself if you have time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62083/discussion-between-meda-and-new-logo).